# Java synchronization modifier

Tags: java, locking

Im trying to understand how the locks using the synchronization keywords in java works. 
if i a have a class (forget about bad practice etc with public vars etc)

```
class Person 
{
    public int money;
    public String name;

    public void give_bonus()
    {
        synchronize(this)
        {
            money += 10;
            name = "....";
        }
    }
}

// thread one 
person.give_bonus();

// thread two
person.money += 50;
```

Now my question is, if i create a lock block using the instance lock (this) will this prevent other threads from manipulating the property money? or do i need to make the money property private and define getter / setter with the synchronize modifier to make sure this value does not risk running into a race condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provide will only prevent other threads from modifying the `money` variable through the `give_bonus()` method until the method returns (or rather, just before the method returns).

As you guess, you will have to make your variable `private` and add synchronization to the setter method to be safe. Just make sure you synchronize on the same lock.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronizing on `this` has nothing at all to do with the contents of `this` object. Java's locking mechanism basically piggiebacks on regular objects, which play another role totally separate from their "objectness". This other role involves a special field in each object, called its *monitor*, recording which thread has acquired it and how many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as if each object instance owns one "ticket" (called its *monitor*). When a thread wants to enter a block that is `synchronized` on a particular object, the thread must first "get the ticket" from the object, and on exiting the block or calling `wait()` it hands the ticket back.

If the ticket is not currently available (because another thread is in the same or another synchronized block that requires the same ticket) then it must wait.

In your example there is nothing to stop thread 2 accessing `money` directly - the fact that thread 1 is in a synchronized block only stops thread 2 from entering a synchronized block on the same monitor at the same time.